# Python - Coding of the Normalized Mean Error

Tags: python, numpy

I have to code the following formula in Python,

[image]

I have tried the following codes, which I though replicated the formula:

```
NME=((np.sum(abs(xdiff)))/(np.sum(abs(np.mean(xobs))-(xobs))))
```

with:

```
xdiff=xmod-xobs
```

with

```
xobs = [12.042314, 6.955123, 6.2299037, 5.130121,  6.7646165, 4.18299]
xmod = [ 0.46322066,  0.419193,  -1.0934393, 7.5015774, 7.6929064, 3.3207343]
```

But it gives me unrealistic values.
Does anyone knows if python/numpy include an automatic Normalized Mean Error command?

Comment: You can do `np.abs(xobs - xmod).sum()/np.abs(xobs.mean()-xobs).sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator has a misplaced parenthesis:

`NME=((np.sum(abs(xdiff)))/(np.sum(abs(np.mean(xobs))-(xobs))))` should be
`NME=((np.sum(abs(xdiff)))/(np.sum(abs(np.mean(xobs)-(xobs)))))`

The absolute value was only affecting the mean value, and thus, the denominator was wrong (very close to zero in your case).